# Android - How to check if any item has been clicked in Drawer Layout?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am displaying all the files of a folder inside a `DrawerLayout` as a `SubMenu`. I am able to do it but I wanna know how to handle the click event if I click on any file inside `DrawerLayout`.

**Here is the Code**

```
public class HTMLEditor extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrawerLayout drawer;
NavigationView navigationView;
Toolbar toolbar;

TextView textViewprojectName;
String projectName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_html_editor);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    projectName = intent.getStringExtra("projectName");

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    View view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    textViewprojectName = view.findViewById(R.id.projectName);
    textViewprojectName.append(" " + projectName);


    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_open, R.string.navigation_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            getString(R.string.app_name) + "/HTML Projects/" + projectName);
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
    SubMenu subMenu = m.addSubMenu("All Files");
    if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
        for (File file : files) {
            subMenu.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,
            new EditorFragment()).commit();

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
{
    // How to handle click event here.
    return false;
}
```

All the files are getting displayed as `SubMenu`. If I click on that file nothing happens. So, I want to get the name of that file (for further use) when I click on any `SubMenu` item.

So, How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subMenu.add(file.getName())` has a return value of type `MenuItem`. You could store all the `MenuItems` that you add in your loop in `onCreate`, e.g.:

```java
List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();

...

if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
    for (File file : files) {
        menuItems.add(subMenu.add(file.getName()));
    }
}
```

and then compare `MenuItem item` in `onNavigationItemSelected` with the items stored:

```java
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
{
    if (menuItems.contains(item)) {
        String filename = item.getTitle(); // this is your filename
    }
    return false;
}
```

In theory, you don't event have to store all items and compare them, assuming all menu entries represent files. Then, you could just access the title via `String filename = item.getTitle()` inside `onNavigationItemSelected`.

Comment: The code is working fine. But I have a question. If I am adding all items of submenu in the list then how it is getting shown in drawer layout?

Comment: The items are still added to `subMenu`, and this is part of the `navigationView`, and this probably part of your `DrawerLayout`. The code I presented does not change the effect of your code to display the items.